# Hibernate: Entities vocabulary(in-memory storage)

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

Vocabularies is common thing when using pure SQL. Just store some static tables(rarely updated entries - such as types, cities list, etc.) in memory and  update when needed - very nice approach because you haven't create tonns of connections and property binding...

But what about Hibernate with it's sessions, transactions, versions, etc. ? Does it allows to create such vocabulary ?

**P.S**. The most interesting thing is - transient objects. Because of number of different sessions and transactions where vocabularies will be used. So each time we get object from vocabulary we have to invoke **merge()** but wouldn't it perform any communication with DB ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate provieds a readonly mapping: [mutable=false](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) (or add @Immutable to your class)
This should result in less memory consumtion.

And you can enable caching for this class.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the vocabulary items are entities in their own right, and references to them are lazy-loaded, Hibernate's second-level cache should allow them to be supplied from memory without going to the database.